# How to return an object from controller to View which may not be model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am very new to MVC and I am not too conversant with the best practices here. I am facing a design issue which may be common or uncommon to newbies like me. My problem is the following:

I have a page with two parts in it.

1. Grid Control (with Employee basic info in it)
2. Employee Details (When someone clicks on Grid row, it loads all the details about the employee)

I am using KendoGrid and it is getting all its data from an ActionMethod from my controller.

Now, when I click on the row, I have the following options:

1. I call some ActionMethod in Controller and return all the Details
2. Should I use partial View with a separate model so that ActionMethod in response calls RenderPartialView()?
3. Should I NOT create a partial View, have Actionmethod return JSON and parse it in the Model?
    3.1 If I go for this option then would the JSON be part of model?
    3.2 If it is not going to be part of model, how can I use JSON to render the View?

Or probably I am missing something basic here?

Comment: Far to opinion based. Personally I would have a view model with 2 properties, one of the `List<Employee>` (to render the grid) and one for `Employee` (to render the form inside a hidden element). Clicking on Edit would display the form as a dialog and populate the form from the table values (or use ajax to return json for the employee if not all details are in the table). Then to save, serialize the form, post it using ajax, update the row value and hide the form. [Refer this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) for simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use action method returning JsonResult. what needs to be done is keep the uielements you need to show on the click of grid row  in the page itself. initiate a ajax call to the action method and on success update the values of the UI elements from the values received in JSON and make the entire DIV as visible which holds the total information.
Instead of passing entire HTML over the network I think you can opt for json.

An example you can find at following location 
[example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748842/Rendering-a-Partial-View-and-JSON-Data-Using-AJAX)

Comment: the example has both the options and a comparison at the end